# got all values of input box are same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a update form. In this when i click on update button i got same values every time that's why update functionality is not working. I already tried to get values using ID attribute of input box but not working. I am new in this field and this task take lots of time. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {               
  $(".update").click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var uname = $(".name1").val();
    var email = $(".email1").val();                    

    $.post("operation.php", {
      ID: id,
      operation: 'update',
      name: 'uname',
      email: 'uemail'
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);                   
    });               
  });
});
```

```php
for($i = 0; $i < $num_of_records; $i++)
{
  echo  "<tr><td>";           
  echo "<input type='text' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"name")." class='name1' id='name' placeholder='Name'><input type='text' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"email")." class='email1' id='email' placeholder='Email'><input type='submit' data-id=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"id")." class='delete' name='delete' id='delete' value='Delete'><input  type='submit' data-id=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"id")." class='update' name='update' id='update' value='Update'>";echo "</td></tr>";            
}
```

Comment: IDs __must__ be unique within an HTML document - so as soon as your loop goes through more than one iteration, you are creating invalid HTML. You need to fix that first of all.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript needs to select the inputs from the same row as the button that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {               
  $(".update").click(function() { 
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var uname = row.find(".name1").val();
    var email = row.find(".email1").val();                    

    $.post("operation.php", {
      ID: id,
      operation: 'update',
      name: 'uname',
      email: 'uemail'
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);                   
    });               
  });
});
```

Comment: You save my time ... Thanks Sir  :))

Answer (score 0):

A better solution do it like this,
I am giving you a small example as your code is bit tidy.

```
<?php
foreach($answers as $a)
{
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-answerid="<?php echo $a->id;?>" class="upvote_link" />Edit</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

jquery Onclick to get clicked value

```
$('.upvote_link').click(function(){
var unique_id = $(this).data('answerid');
console.log(unique_id);
});
```

Shoot a comment if you have any issue executing this.You should always write unique id in html elements. Javascript should be knowing that particular link is been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `id`s are same, so jQuery stops searching as soon as it matches the first element with that ID.
To prevent this from happening, use the .siblings() function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {               
  $(".update").click(function() { 
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var uname = $(this).siblings(".name1").val();
    var email = $(this).siblings(".email1").val();                    

    $.post("operation.php", {
      ID: id,
      operation: 'update',
      name: 'uname',
      email: 'uemail'
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);                   
    });               
  });
});
```